# Can you both export and use a variable in the same GEE script?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Let's say I have too files, library, and main

content of library:

```
exports.someVariable = 5;
```

content of main:

```
var library = require('path/to/library')
print(library.someVariable) // correctly prints 5
```

But let's say I want to also use someVariable in library, maybe something like this:

content of library:

```
exports.someVariable = 5;
exports.someOtherVariable = someVariable+3; //will say it doesn't exist in this scope
```

What I tried
content of library:

```
var someVariable = 5;
var someOtherVariable = someVariable+3; //it works so far
exports.someVariable;
exports.someOtherVariable;
```

content of main:

```
var library = require('path/to/library')
print(library.someVariable) // undefined
print(library.someOtherVariable) // undefined
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is the first time I'm answering my own question, and I always thought it's odd to answer your own question. Why ask if you know the answer, are people just bragging, but I digress, I figured out the answer while asking the question, so asking was very useful.

What I was missing is that `exports.someVariable` is a public separate variable that will be then available in main. The variable is obviously undefined until I put something in it, but I can't use it in lib (at least not in an obvious way). The way to go is to do your thing with regular variables (declared with `var`) and then at the end expose whatever variables you want to be public (accessible from main). Something like this:

content of library:

```
var someVariable = 5;
var someOtherVariable = someVariable+3; //it works so far
exports.someVariable = someVariable; they don't even need to be called the same, but probably that's what you want
exports.someOtherVariable = someOtherVariable;
```

content of main:

```
var library = require('path/to/library')
print(library.someVariable) // 5
print(library.someOtherVariable) // 8
library.someVariable = library.someOtherVariable + 2
print(library.someVariable) // 10
```